# hide tabbarcontroller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitabbarcontroller

I have a UITabBarController with multiple tabs. When i push a viewController that is a gallery, i hide the tab bar using `self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES` but i need to navigate from this gallery to another view controller and the tab bar controller should be displayed.

I acomplish this by setting `self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = NO` in the gallery before pushing the new view controller. The trouble is that when i go back to the gallery, the tab bar controller is visible. How can i hide it again for the gallery?

Comment: where are you writing the code to hide tabbar code?

Comment: you cannot hide it on the base/root controller. create a virtual view controller in that, create your base viewcontroller's object and set hidebottombarwhenpushed = YES; and push view controller.

Comment: @Stark in the init of the gallery and before i push the new controller

Answer (score 3):

In the `-(void) viewWillAppear` method, add this line to hide the tabbar:

```
 [[[self navigationController] tabBarController] tabBar].hidden = YES;
```

Comment: ... or perhaps in `viewWillAppear` because OP did mention about the tab bar not hiding when the view is displayed the second time.

Comment: this hides it but the problem is that there remains a chunk of space where i should have the tab bar, which doesn't actually hides it, it kind of makes it invisible only. i need something like 'remove it temporarely'

Comment: Would self.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES; in the viewController solve that?

Comment: I think then you could force it by setting it manually, using something like: `self.view.frame = CGRectMake(<#CGFloat x#>, <#CGFloat y#>, <#CGFloat width#>, <#CGFloat height#>+tabbarHeight);`

Answer (score 0):

You can add show and hide code in proper views delegate method viewWillAppear

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could set the MyTabBarController.view.hidden property to YES when you go back to your gallery and load it.

Comment: this hides the entire view  [[self navigationController] tabBarController].view.hidden = YES;